# scikit-learn Standard Scaler - get the standard deviation in the original unscaled space for GMM

Tags: scikit-learn

Before running a GMM clustering model, I use a standard Scaler to transform my data into a 0 mean,  1 std dataset

Having then performed clustering, I am interested in representing the learned cluster back in the original space rather than the 0-mean, 1 standard deviation, where the feature values make more sense.

Is it then correct to do the following:

1. Get the mean by multiplying the mean of each GMM cluster by the
   scaler.mean_ parameters.
2. Get the standard deviation by multiplying the square of the
   diagonal covariance matrix by the scaler.std_ parameters.

I'd appreciate any feedback,

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the cluster centers you can use `scaler.inverse_transform()` directly (because they live in the same space as your data). It adds the column means back and scales each column back up by its standard deviation.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = np.random.randn(10, 3)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
```

You will then see that

```
scaler.inverse_transform(scaler.transform(X)) - X
```

is equal or extremely close to `0`, making the two essentially equal. In order to automate you r pipeline, you should also take a look at `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`, with which you can concatenate your processes and invoke `transform` and `inverse_transform` methods.

As for the rescaling of the covariance, you should multiply `np.diag(scaler.std_)` to the right and to the left of your cluster covariance matrices.

To answer your question:

1) You obtain the mean by *multiplying* the cluster means by scaler.std_ and *adding* scaler.mean_ back.
2) You rescale the cluster covariances by multiplying left and right by, `np.diag(scaler.std_)`, viz `rescaled_cov = np.diag(scaler.std_).dot(cov).dot(np.diag(scaler.std_))`

Note: If your covariance matrices are rather large, you may not want to create another (diagonal, but dense) matrix of the same size. The operation `scaler.std_[:, np.newaxis] * cov * scaler.std_` is equivalent mathematically to 2) but does not require creating the diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eickenberg! It makes better sense to add the mean back to the product. Could you clarify the reasoning for rescaling the covariance. How do I derive this expression? rescaled_cov = np.diag(scaler.std_).dot(cov).dot(np.diag(scaler.std_))

Comment: Actually, i think np.diag(scaler.std_).dot(cov).dot(np.diag(scaler.std_)) makes sense as it will 1) scale up the variance by sigma_i^2 for each feature x_i and 2) recover the other covariances by multiplying the scaled covariance of each pair x_i x_j by the corresponding product of standard deviations sigma_i * sigma_j

Comment: Can you kindly tell how to find maximum likelyhood for each iteration while applying GMM.